# Will it be possible to update RealTime document data after the Realtime API is shut down in January 2018?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-realtime-api

The Realtime API deprecation page says it will be possible to use: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get even after the RealTime API is shot down.

Will it also be possible to update real time documents using this? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/update

As far as I understand these are only exports/imports so it should work even after the RealTime API infrastructure is gone.

Comment: I think so, but you can [import realtime data to Cloud Firestore](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/migration#importing_realtime_data_to_cloud_firestore). This way you can readily change your realtime codes if first option (use realtime.get and realtime.update) fails.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rebot. The issue with using Cloud Firestore is that it's not build on the top of Google Drive which makes managing and sharing files really easy. We are planning to use simple JSON files inside Google Drive together with Firebase, however, it would be great if the old realtime files behave as JSON files on Google Drive so that users can keep using old realtime documents.